# How to update the binary by go install?

Tags: go

I used to be able to install a go binary package by:

```
go get -u github.com/some_user/some_project
```

Now it does work any more, and after some googling, I learned an alternative:

```
go install github.com/some_user/some_project@latest
```

So far so good, but now I pushed a change to the master branch, and I was expecting to run the same go install command again to update the binary file installed, but it didn't. I wonder what the equivalent of `go get -u` will be with `go install`.

Comment: Taking a look at the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Add_dependencies_to_current_module_and_install_them) should answer some of your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it's not because of github delay. Github is a git repository, once you push your changes, your code repository gets updated immediately. It's because of `goproxy`. Goproxy is a centralized repository for go packages, and that's there to avoid (as much as possible) some problems with manually version updating to the code repository and many other reasons, which I'm not going to get deep into, read more [here](https://jfrog.com/blog/why-goproxy-matters-and-which-to-pick/). goproxy wont index every code repository in real time, so that's why you couldn't see your changes. Indeed, you can tell go to not to use the go proxy, and use the github directly:

```bash
GOPROXY=direct go get -u github.com/some/package
```

The direct here means to use the github here directly, it can be any other repository.